# passing an array of hashMap to an IReport table

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource, subreport

I'm very new in *iReport* Designer.

I'm using *iReport 5.5.0* and having problem to put a passed array of hashmaps: `Map<String, Object>[]` in my table.

It works fine when I don't use *JasperReports* table and just put fields next to each other in *Detail* band.

but when I use *JasperReports* table:

1. either my table repeats for each individual row(using following datasource expression):

   ```
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]>
   </dataSourceExpression>
   ```
2. or I have a table with correct row numbers and only one correctly filled row:

   ```
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
   ```

I tried to put my table in summary or title bands

also tried using defining a new `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource` in master report and using it in datasourceExpression, but none of these worked.\
what should I do?

Comment: If you are using UI of the iReports, make sure the data field is not crossing border of `Detail` band.

Comment: yes I'm using UI of iReports and no it didn't cross border of detail band. I adapted the table to detail band.